# Form within iframe doesn't run properly

Tags: php, html, forms, iframe

I am trying to execute a simple 'get' form within an iframe like so:

```html
<iframe width = 60% height= 100% id="dynamic-content" src="imageViewing.php" />
```

This is the imageViewing.php:

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="8">
<?php
//*database conncetion settings*
$query = "SELECT team_name,id,content FROM upload WHERE display='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $id = $row['id'];
 echo $row['id']. '<img width="200" height = "200" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['content']) . ' " />'. $row['team_name']."<form method='get' action='imgApproved.php?id='$id'><input type='submit' value='Approve'/></form><br>";
}
exit;
mysql_close();
?>
</html>
```

Clicking the button runs the imgApprove.php, which changes the 'display' parameter for the specific image, so that it doesn't display the next time the iframe refreshes.

```html
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 //*Connect to database stuff*
 $query = "UPDATE upload SET display='0' WHERE id='$id'";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_error());
 header("location:imageViewing.php");
}
?>
```

However, when I click on Approve, the iframe stops refreshing and no longer displays anything. However, if I refresh the page all the images are still displayed (so I assume imgApprove.php hasnt changed the value of display). Am I missing something simple here?

**EDIT** I have been doing some further testing and as it turns out: `if (isset($_GET['id']))` is returning false and not even running the code, so the problem must be in the passing of the $id variable.

Comment: First thing, you should avoid mysql_* functions since it's deprecated and marked for removal. Consider using Mysqli or, even better, PHP Data Objects (PDO). The way your code is presented is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I am using web hosting site, which supports PHP5.3 and nothing newer. In what way is my code vulnerable (i don't fully understand sql security just yet)

Comment: Mysqli was implemented in verison 5.3.0 by the way. Read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Also, your code is a bit confusing. Once you click Approve, what should happen? You're fetching "display" values from "upload" table given ID argument, storing it inside an array `$row` and changing it's `display` field value to 0, then redirecting the page back to previous page. What is that you want to happen?

Comment: Once I click 'Approve' -> imgApprove.php should run and change the 'display' on the current image (find this with id) and return to the previous page. I now see what the problem is - rather than changing the actual value of the 'display' within the table i am only locally assigning something to $row['display']

Comment: I have edited the OP and fixed what you were referring to; however, it still does has the same effect -> once clicked the iframe simply stops working. (I will get rid of the deprecated mysql tomorrow as well)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87180/discussion-between-aedix-rhinedale-and-oliver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was caused by an unclosed iframe. I needed to add `</iframe>` after the `<iframe>` declaration. Anything in between the two is the text displayed if the iframe fails to load.